# Why does Swagger Codegen convert an ON/OFF string enum to TRUE/FALSE?

Tags: yaml, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am using Swagger Codegen 3.0.19, also tried OpenAPI Generator 4.0.3.

Java Environment:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Runner:

```
java -jar ./libs/openapi-generator-cli-4.3.0.jar  generate \
       -i pet.yaml \
       -g spring \
       -o ./OUTPUT/api/
```

Here's my OpenAPI Schema:

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.0"
....
CaptureStatus:
  type: object
  description: Holds current capture status.
  properties:
    status:
      type: string
      enum:
        - ON
        - OFF
      description: Capture status values.
....
```

Output is:

```java
  ....
  public enum StatusEnum {
    TRUE("true"),

    FALSE("false");

    private String value;

    StatusEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  ....
```

Why does the codegen translate the ON/OFF enum to TRUE/FALSE? It does not do it when I generate using Swagger Editor GUI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In YAML 1.1, `on`, `off`, `y`, `n`, `yes` and `no` are [boolean values](https://yaml.org/type/bool.html). This was [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42284910/113116) in YAML 1.2, this version no longer considers these values as booleans.

It looks like Swagger Codegen and OpenAPI Generator use YAML 1.1 parsers. In this case you need to enclose `'ON'` and `'OFF'` in quotes to treat them as strings:

```
      enum:
        - 'ON'
        - 'OFF'
```

Comment: It worked but still curious why it works from swagger editor gui and not from command line. Anyways i have enough to continue now. Thank you.

Comment: Swagger Editor converts YAML to JSON before sending it to the codegen. Editor uses YAML 1.2 parser so it translates `enum: [ON, OFF]` to `"enum": ["ON", "OFF"]` (i.e. string enum, not boolean enum) without having to add quotes to the original values. That's why the editor's codegen produces correct result.